# How to access Terminal Rosetta as a terminal in Intellij IDEA CE on M1 Mac?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, apple-m1

I'm working on a codebase that require openjadk@8 specifically. I've a M1 Mac chip while openjdk8 is for intel chips and not for for m1 chips.
[image]
So I've configured Rosetta terminal on, which is an Apple built emulator  translates layer for running Intel-based apps on Apple Silicon Macs.
Rosetta 2 terminal: https://www.courier.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-to-setup-your-apple-m1-for-development/

I'm unable to get this rosetta based terminal on Intellij IDEA CE.
[image]
[[image]]

I'm able to open default terminal and the one with rosetta outside the intellij idea ce.
[image]

Now, please help to use to use terminal with rosetta inside intellij idea.

Comment: You can simply start a x86 shell using `arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [this discussion](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010485779-is-it-possible-to-run-the-terminal-through-rosetta-for-arm-), use the following as the Terminal shell path:

```
env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh
```

Comment: Thanks. So,in conclusion, these 2 commands can be used to switch between the two types of terminal.
env /usr/bin/arch -arm64 /bin/zsh 
env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh

Comment: Note that they don't technically "switch", but just launch a new shell with the desired architecture. That means if you do that 10 times, you have 10 nested shells (not to terrible, but takes up memory).